# How can I get a list of packages that I have installed using apt-get?

Tags: apt

I want to get a list of packages that I have installed using `apt-get`.

i.e. any packages that I have installed since my Linode (Debian) was initially created.

Is this possible?

Comment: both answers here mention the `history.log` files in `/var/log/apt/`.  It's important to note that, by default, logrotate is configured to keep only the last 12 months worth of these files.  The same is true of `the /dpkg.log` files in `/var/log` (which provide similar infomation in an (IMO) more-easily parsed format).  Edit `/etc/logrotate.d/{apt,dpkg}` to change retention policy for your system.

Answer (score 32):

You can list installed package using `apt` using the following command:

```
apt --installed list
```

**Edit**

Use the following command to list installed package through `apt-get` :

```
zcat /var/log/apt/history.log.*.gz | cat - /var/log/apt/history.log | grep -Po '^Commandline: apt-get install (?!.*--reinstall)\K.*'
```

[Source: Askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/680417/498780)

Comment: As you have stated that lists all packages installed. I want packages that I have manually installed using `apt-get` commands.

Comment: @user598200 - Consider accepting this answer. :)

Comment: Based on [this askubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/250530/349837) I get to `(zcat $(ls -tr /var/log/apt/history.log*.gz); cat /var/log/apt/history.log) 2>/dev/null |  egrep '^(Commandline: apt(-get)? install)' |  grep -v aptdaemon |  egrep '^Commandline:'`

Comment: `zgrep -hPo '^Commandline: apt-get install (?!.*--reinstall)\K.*' /var/log/apt/history.log{.*.gz,}` produces the same output without the unnecessary `zcat` and `cat`.  if you don't care about the exact order of package names in the output, `/var/log/apt/history.log*` will do for the filename argument.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to display only a list with the packages you have **manually installed** you could run:

```
apt --installed list | grep -v automatic
```

to not list packages flagged as automatically installed

```
-v, --invert-match   Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.
```

Another option that won't erroneously exclude an unfortunate package with "automatic" in its name is:

```
apt-mark showmanual
```

Comment: Short and sweet, and sorted alphabetically.

Comment: If by chance a package name contains "automatic" it will be filtered out by grep.

Answer (score 7):

```
zgrep -h ' install ' /var/log/dpkg.log* | sort | awk '{print $4}'
```

This will give you a list of packages that have been installed, in the order that they were installed.

As per my comment, only the last 12 months worth of`/var/log/dpkg.log*` files are kept by default.  To change this, edit `/etc/logrotate.d/dpkg`.  For example, change `rotate 12` to `rotate 1200` to keep the last 1200 months (100 years) worth - effectively forever, never delete the old logs.

BTW, if you want to see when packages were upgraded, change `install` to `upgrade`.  e.g.

```
zgrep -h ' upgrade ' /var/log/dpkg.log* | sort
```

same for `remove` and `purge`.

Answer (score 3):

This relies on `aptitude`, but the following will give you a list of packages that are manually installed, i.e. aren't installed just because of dependency:

```
aptitude search -F %p '~i!~M'
```

Depending on how the image is setup, it will probably also include some installed by the base system. You can get rid of a fair bit of those by switching them to being automatically installed, then just mark as manual the few you want to keep despite not having anything depending on them. This is easy to do with M inside `aptitude` on a bare system.

Answer (score 1):

Use `dpkg` to list all packages installed on a system: `dpkg --get-selections`

To list all packages installed using `apt-get` look at `/var/log/apt/history.log`. This log also contains packages you have removed. You can `grep` for the lines that start with `Install:`.

Comment: As you have stated that lists all packages installed. I want packages that I have manually installed using `apt-get` commands.

Comment: @user598200 Ah. Thank you for clarifying. See my edited answer. I am not sure if `apt-get` has that functionality. But whenever you install something, it is appended to the log file I mention in the answer.

Comment: Thanks. Any way I can go through all of the `/var/log/apt/history.log*` files and print out the package names in one hit?

Comment: @user598200 You could use `grep`. `grep "Install: package" /var/log/apt/history.log*`

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 14.04 and above use `apt list --installed` for older versions use `dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall`

Answer (score 1):

A bit shorter and sorted

```
gunzip -c /var/log/apt/history.log.*.gz | grep 'apt-get install' | cut -f4- -d" " | tr ' ' $'\n' | sort -u
```

Comment: Some explanation as to why this is better than the answer @GAD3R gave would be helpful.

Comment: First of all, it's shorter, second of all the output is sorted

Comment: The idea on U&L is that you improve your answer (or question in case you had posted one) by editing the post, instead of hiding valuable information in comments. As I would cut and paste the command the 26 bytes less is not so interesting, but the fact that your output is sorted really belongs in the answer itself. If such an improvement was as a reaction to a request for clarification a simple "updated my answer" as comment will do, the commenter (in this case me) will get notified of that comment. I think the terseness also is the cause that someone downvoted your answer.

Comment: If you want to play golf then try `zgrep -Pho '(?<=apt-get install ).*' /var/log/apt/history.log.*.gz | tr ' ' $'\n' | sort -u`.